# caller App delayed

Tags: calls, xiaomi

I use a Xiaomi Poco F3, the caller App is from Google (Phone 73.0.414822266).

When the phone starts ringing (a call) the "answer" button does not appear instantly, but only after 10 seconds. It's not convenient because often people have already hung up before I have time to answer.

What can I do to repair this problem?

Comment: I think I usually encountered this issue for numbers that are considered spam. You may try disabling the Caller ID & Spam filter by following [these steps](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/3459196). (I've just disabled it now for an experiment, but I seldom get any calls, so I can't test the result quickly)

Comment: @Andrew seems to work! Thanks so much

Comment: Kind of surprising, but good to know. Perhaps wait for a few days to ensure that it's really fixed though. After that, feel free to post a self-answer :)

Comment: @Andrew alas, apart from once or twice, the problem remained unchanged

Comment: The same happened to me... one non-contact call was still delayed, but a spam call was shown (ironically)...